# Taxonomy hierarchy is not working [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Taxonomy hierarchy is not working right in my theme.
Wordpress grab the taxonomy.php for all my custom taxonomies.

When taxonomy.php is removed from theme folder it’s working fine.

It looks like the hierarchy for taxonomy is upside down.

Archives works well.

Comment: I have occured exact same problem working on my project recently. Using  newest Wordpress.

It seems like Wordpress template hierarchy has changed at some point. For example for custom taxonomy "product_category", taxonomy-product_category.php template should be grabbed first,  despite this, for some reason Wordpress takes taxonomy.php...

Answer (score -1):

It seems it is working fine with all WordPress versions and general themes.

Please read this below description

**Taxonomy Template Hierarchy**

WordPress display posts in the order determined by the Template Hierarchy.

The category.php, tag.php, and taxonomy.php templates allow posts filtered by taxonomy to be treated differently from unfiltered posts or posts filtered by a different taxonomy. (Note: post refers to any post type – posts, pages, custom post types, etc.). These files let you target specific taxonomies or specific taxonomy terms. For example:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
tag-{slug}.php
tag-{id}.php
category-{slug}.php
category-{ID}.php
```

So you could format all posts in an animal taxonomy named news on a page that looks different from posts filtered in other categories.

The archive.php template provides the most general form of control, providing a layout for all archives; that is, a page that displays a list of posts.

You can also read full official description on this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).

If still you find problem just change theme to twenty-seventy of wordpress then check. Also you can try by just flushing permalink structure from setting.

Comment: How can you tell if it works on all versions if you didn't even know his version of Wordpress? The question was **not** about **how it works**, but **why it does not work correctly** with this hierarchy. E.g: i have **taxonomy** named **cars** so template should be _taxonomy-cars.php_, right? It works fine if it's the only _taxonomy_ template file, but when there's also _taxonomy.php_, wordpress grabs it first.